# calling JQuery HTTP GET request inside javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I will start off by saying I am new to Javascript and JQuery. What I want to accomplish is have a submit button on an HTML page that will call the `dbQuery` function in my `.js` file that will print the value of variables to the screen and then add them into a MySQL database.

I need to use the JavaScript variable `selectedVisibleValue` that is defined in my first function `dbQuery` The reason I want to do this is because I have four drop downs, three of which are hidden drop downs that are only shown depending on the first non hidden dropdown, only one of the hidden drop downs is ever visible.

I want to work with these variables in my PHP page `formPage` to do the Database functions. My code is below I want to add the `testing1` function into the `dbQuery` function.

I have tried just copying and pasting it into the `dbQuery` function but it does not work. I am not trying to work with the `selectedVisibleValue` in the code below. I am just trying to do some testing with some bogus variables.

```
    var dbQuery = function(){
    var description = document.getElementById("jobDescription").value;
    var selectedEquip = document.getElementById("equipmentList");
    var selectedEquip1 = selectedEquip.options[selectedEquip.selectedIndex].text;
    var selectedVisibleValue = $(".unitDropDowns select:visible").val();
    document.getElementById("descriptionSummary").innerHTML = "<h3>Description</h3>" + "<p>" + description + "</p>";
    document.getElementById("equipmentRan").innerHTML = "<h3>Equipment Ran </h3>" + "<p>" + selectedEquip1 + "</p>" + "<h3>Unit Number</h3>" + "<p>" + selectedVisibleValue + "</p>";
    document.getElementById("equipmentRan").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("descriptionSummary").style.display = "block";
}

var testing1 = function() {
    $.get(
        "formPage.php",
     {paramOne : 123, paramX : 'abc'},
     function(data) {
     document.getElementById("equipmentRan").innerHTML = ('page content: ' + data);
    }
);
}
```

Comment: What does not work here?

Comment: I don't think its executing the code for the `testing1` function it will show everything how its supposed to in the `dbQuery` function but the values from the `testing1` function are never printed to the screen. If I call the `testing1` function from a separate submit button it works as intended. I do not receive any errors in the console either.

Comment: I would wrap your `$.get` in a `jQuery Document Ready` function to see if that fixes it.

Comment: I realize that I basically want both of them to execute from the click of a single submit button I have tried calling it from inside the `dbQuery` function and it did not work.

Comment: `did not work` is not very helpful. Need to learn how to inspect request in browser console( check status, what is sent/received etc), and make sure no script errors are being thrown also. Need a lot more details since problem  could be script or server related

Comment: Remember that using `var =` inside a function makes it ***private***. If you need to use `selectedVisibleValue` variable outside that function, make it ***public***.

Comment: Since you have anyway included jQuery in your page, you might as well use its facilties (instead of getEl..Id, .innerHTML, .style.block etc..) to make your code way shorter than what it is now.

Comment: You wrote ***add them into a MySQL database*** yet your using `.get()`. Having said that, you may want to use a `POST` method instead.

Comment: I think I now see the OP's problem: The SQL POST is happening at the same time the `dbQuery()` is invoked. That means the `.get()` may not retrieve the newly posted content in question. Please clarify OP: Am I understanding your problem correctly?

Comment: I havent added any of the SQL functions to the PHP file yet I am just echoing the variable values to verify they have been passed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/f9zWT/)

Passing variables between functions might come in useful for your project.

**HTML:**

```html
<div id="theBox"></div>
<button>Press Me</button>
```

**JS**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    // This is some other Do More function, defined prior to the next variable function.
    // This is your .get() request.
    function doMore(target){
        // For the incomming targer, add a class style of a larger font.
        $(target).css('font-size', 30);
    }    


    // The main function.    
    var dbQuery = function() {
        // Show dynamic text on the HTML page.
        var extra = $('#theBox').html('Dynamic Text Results');
        // Run some other function, also... send the private variable in use.
        doMore(extra);        
    };


    // The submit button.
    $('button').on('click', function() {
        // Start the function.
        dbQuery();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
//cache references to static elements
var jobDescription = $('#jobDescription')
  , selectedEquip = $('#equipmentList')
  , descriptionSummary = $('#descriptionSummary')
  , equipmentRan = $('#equipmentRan')
  ;    


function dbQuery(){

    //gather params    
    var params = {
        jobDescription : jobDescription.val(),
        selectedEquip1 : selectedEquip.val(),
        selectedVisibleValue = $(".unitDropDowns select:visible").val()
    }

    //show summary
    descriptionSummary.html('<h3>Description</h3><p>'+description+'</p></h3>').show();
    equipmentRan.html('<h3>Equipment Ran</h3><p>'+selectedEquip1+'</p><h3>Unit Number</h3><p>'+selectedVisibleValue+'</p>').show();

    //do a get
    $.get('formPage.php',params,function(data) {
        equipmentRan.html('page content: ' + data);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code:

```
        function dbQuery() {
    window.description = document.getElementById("jobDescription").value;
    var selectedEquip = document.getElementById("equipmentList");
    window.selectedEquip1 = selectedEquip.options[selectedEquip.selectedIndex].text;
    window.selectedVisibleValue = $(".unitDropDowns select:visible").val();
    testing1();
}

function testing1() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.get(
        "formPage.php",
     {paramOne : window.selectedVisibleValue, paramX : window.description, paramY : window.selectedEquip1},
     function(data) {
     document.getElementById("equipmentRan").innerHTML = (data);
    }
);
});
}
```

Comment: In comments a while back, I mentioned you should wrap your `.get()` in a `jQuery Document Ready` function. I use that globally in my jsFiddle for my Answer, where also I show how you can run a secondary function that can launch the `.get();` function. Reconsider my answer.